# Nginx SSL Rewrite Exeption for yust one folder

Tags: nginx, exclude

i force visitors to SSL on two ways in my serverblock

```
        if ($http_x_forwarded_proto = "http") {
     return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
    }
```

and

```
add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000;includeSubdomains; preload";
```

My issue now is that some scripts aren't able to connect to ssl, i think they will not react to STS but is it possible to exclude only one folder from the rewrite without further trouble? I would like to exclude website.org/feed

Answer (score 0):

Fixed. To exclude files from the Rewrite is pretty easy, instead of the `server` block, the SSL Rewrite should be in the `location` Block like

```
location / {
    if ($http_x_forwarded_proto = "http") {
        return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
    }
}
```

After the exclude

```
location /feed/ {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your sollution is too complex. Just create a simple redirect in your website config:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name yourwebsite.com;

    return 301 https://yourwebsite.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name yourwebsite.com;

    Your...;
    Original...;
    Code...;
    ...;
}
```